# Listen flink JobStatus changes

Tags: apache-flink

I would like to know when the status of a Flink job changes in a local execution environment; this would be useful to write more resilient tests as the other alternatives I found so far are about relaxing timeouts and similar.

Even polling is an improvement from where I am now if there is a function that I can call for getting the current status.

I see that there are a couple of classes that seem promising in the API docs but I can't really find a way to wire them in a meaningful way in order to get this working.

Comment: hi @aldo, could you find out how to do this?